# fetchedResultsController doesn't filter (fetchRequest)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to fetch a list of entities filtering by one of its properties (word), I'm using a **fetchedResultsController** for that and everything looks ok. The list is loaded and showed on my tableView, I'm even able to sort the list, but when I tried to filter it using **predicate** nothing happens. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I tried the apple website and some questions from stackoverflow and I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code for **fetchedResultsController**

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<TranslationContainer> = {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<TranslationContainer>()

    let entity = TranslationContainer.entity()
    fetchRequest.entity = entity


    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "word == %@", "Bed")// doesn't filter
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate


    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "word", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext,
        sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
        cacheName: "TranslationContainers")
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

Any suggestion would be really appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the problem, actually the problem was the cache `cacheName: "TranslationContainers"` . It didn't updated after I add the code for filtering. I just changed the cache's name and worked out!

Answer (score 4):

NSFetchedResultsController optionally caches results and the cache content may get out of sync if you just change the NSPredicate like the code above does. One way to get around this is to delete the cache before you set the new predicate:

```
NSFetchedResultsController.deleteCache(withName: "TranslationContainers")
fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest?.predicate = predicate
```